# Parsing Remote Files

Tags: mount, remote

I have two systems. I have some log files on one system (A) that are being generated every hour. I want to parse those files from another system (B).
One way is to copy the files and then parse them on (B). But this will consume a lot of bandwidth to copy and if I parse the files on original system (A) it will increase the CPU utilization, which I must avoid.

Can somebody suggest the most optimal way of doing this?
In simple words, what I want is: Use system B to parse the files located on Remote System A so that I don't have much load on system A (regardless of load on system B) whilst also the load on the network is optimized.

Comment: If the file is on B and you want to parse it on A, you will have to transfer the contents.  What makes you think it's faster to "transfer" the files than to copy them?  Aren't you moving the same data?

Comment: how big are these files? copying text files should not consume much bandwidth. nor should parsing them consume much CPU for that matter,

Answer (score 0):

f they are just standard text files, you can probably get close to 90% compression rates if you compress them before sending. There will be some load while compressing them, but probably less than what analyzing would cost.

Edit: due to the comments, I should also suggest using HTTP compression and serving the log files to the remote machine for parsing. It will still generate load to compress the pages, but maybe your web server will do a better job at balancing the resources versus firing off 7-Zip in the background.

Comment: compression is bound to be more CPU intensive than parsing the files remotely. The OP wants to minimise cpu load on the remote system.

Comment: -1  Wrong answer.  This is almost certainly a much heavier load on _both_ ends than simply pumping the data across a network.

Comment: True, but he wants to minimize CPU load and network traffic. I guess parsing remotely with HTTP compression would be the best option.